# Wiregurd connected but no internet access

Tags: networking, internet, vpn, wireguard

I was using a virtual machine for work and Wireguard was working fine on it but when I tried to connect with the same config to my laptop it's connecting with no errors but no internet access
note: I stopped Wireguard on the virtual machine
I am using ubuntu version 20.04.2 on Lenovo ThinkPad E15
I tried running a different config and got the same problem and tried to reinstall Wireguard
I also tried it on a different laptop running windows 10 and tried to change my router but still the same problem

Comment: Sharing your server and client config files may help. Please mask private keys.

Answer (score 0):

[ Solved ] I contacted my internet provider and they changed the DNS server to another one that supports VPN or something like that